# Why do we only consider relative motion of hydrogenic atoms?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

In my lectures on quantum mechanics, it was said that the Hamiltonian for a hydrogenic atom could be split into relative motion and translational motion, as follows:

$$\hat{H} = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2_{cm} - \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\nabla^2 - \frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}$$

and that one only need consider the relative motion:

$$\hat{H} = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\nabla^2 - \frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}$$

This statement is reiterated in Atkins' *Physical Chemistry (10th Edition)*, as well as his *Molecular Quantum Mechanics (4th Edition)*, and various other online resources, but I am yet to find an explanation as to why.

Why *can* we, and why *do* we, neglect the translational motion of the atom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do that because the variables have *separated*. The Hamiltonian of relative motion depends on the relative coordinates. The translational part depends on the coordinates of the center of mass. The two never mix. They don't interact; they don't even *care* about each other.

Separation of variables in various guises is an immensely powerful technique of solving PDE. You will encounter it time and again, including *this very chapter* of whatever textbook you are using, just a few lines below, when you'll start to actually solve the equation for hydrogen atom by splitting it into radial and angular parts.

So it goes.

Comment: I understand separability but the author goes on to write $- \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\nabla^2 - \frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r} = E\Psi$, declaring it *the* Schrödinger equation for a hydrogenic atom. What is the physical intuition behind seemingly totally discarding the translational motion? (i.e. how can you disregard translational motion and still set the result equal to $E$?)

Comment: This is $E$ of relative motion. Translational motion is associated with its own kinetic energy; it can be anything, so why bother.